# discord bot bot not defined

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import requests
import os 

TOKEN = os.getenv("TOKEN")


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "hello":
        await message.channel.send("world")


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

when I start the bot in python I get the error that the bot is not defined

```
@bot.event
NameError: name 'bot' is not defined
```

Comment: I suppose you are missing `bot = discord.Client()`

Comment: Indeed, your problem is described in the text of the error itself: `'bot' is not defined`. You need to either import something called `bot`, or have an assignment statement somewhere above the first time you reference it in your program (e.g. `bot=(something)`)

Answer (score 0):

you need to construct a bot first so like this

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import requests
import os 

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())
TOKEN = os.getenv("TOKEN")


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "hello":
        await message.channel.send("world")


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't made the bot yet. You are running `bot.run()` even though you don't have `bot` declared as a variable. To fix this make a discord.ext bot or a discord client.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import requests
import os 

TOKEN = os.getenv("TOKEN")

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="your prefix here", intents=discord.Intents.default())
# If you want more intents, do discord.Intents.all()
# or call them manually with intents.message_content = True

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "hello":
        await message.channel.send("world")


bot.run(TOKEN)
```